# Issue with cannot resolve method & symbol

Tags: java, math, gyroscope, epsilon

From this code I have a few issue with the sqrt, sin & cos cannot resolve method and the EPSILON cannot resolve symbol. Do I need to add in math library for the sin cos & sqrt? If yes can you give me the link to download the jar?

```
float omegaMagnitude = sqrt(axisX*axisX + axisY*axisY + axisZ*axisZ);

        // Normalize the rotation vector if it's big enough to get the axis
        // (that is, EPSILON should represent your maximum allowable margin of error)
        if (omegaMagnitude > EPSILON) {
            axisX /= omegaMagnitude;
            axisY /= omegaMagnitude;
            axisZ /= omegaMagnitude;
        }

        // Integrate around this axis with the angular speed by the timestep
        // in order to get a delta rotation from this sample over the timestep
        // We will convert this axis-angle representation of the delta rotation
        // into a quaternion before turning it into the rotation matrix.
        float thetaOverTwo = omegaMagnitude * dT / 2.0f;
        float sinThetaOverTwo = sin(thetaOverTwo);
        float cosThetaOverTwo = cos(thetaOverTwo);
```

Comment: JAR?  This is Java?  Those should be Math.sqrt, Math.sin and Math.cos.  EPSILON should be defined as a double by you.  No libraries needed.

Comment: I suspect that the code you copied and pasted has `import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;` (and same for the other functions, and similar for the EPSILON constant).

Comment: I have tried using import static java.lang.Math.sqrt; but the float omegaMagnitude = sqrt(axisX*axisX + axisY*axisY + axisZ*axisZ);  is underlined in red. For the EPSILON im not really sure how to define it as double.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to download any additional libraries.
Use `Math.sin(x), Math.cos(x) and Math.sqrt(x)` or `sin(x), cos(x) and sqrt(x)` and place the following code at the top of your file (but below the line `package  [...]`, if it exists):

```
// For Math.xxx()
import java.lang.Math;

// For xxx()
import static java.lang.Math.sin;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
```

If you're using Eclipse just press `Ctrl + Shift + O` to automatically organize your imports (there should be similar shortcuts for other IDE's).